# removeOverlay in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

How can I port this to v3? removeOverlay is not included in v3.

```
if( mapElements[lMapElementIndex]['marker'] != 0 ){
  //map.removeOverlay(mapElements[lMapElementIndex]['marker']); V2
}
```

V3?

```
if( mapElements[lMapElementIndex]['marker'] != 0 ){
  //map.removeOverlay(mapElements[lMapElementIndex]['marker']);
  mapElements(mapElements[lMapElementIndex]['marker']).setMap(null);
} //but throws an error mapElements is not a function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `setMap` method of the overlay. [From the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#RemovingOverlays):

> To remove an overlay from a map, call the overlay's `setMap()` method,
>   passing `null`.

Assuming `mapElements` is an array of objects, and that the `marker` property refers to an overlay instance, then all you need to do is:

```
mapElements[lMapElementIndex]['marker'].setMap(null);
```

Your attempt throws an error because you are trying to call `mapElements` as a function (when it appears to be an array). There is no need for that. Just get rid of the function call and it should work fine.

Comment: thanks i know its setMap(null)...but not rlly sure how do i change this to the removeFromMap(lMapElementIndex) function (see the source: http://pastebin.com/EFwnngnR ) line: 573

Comment: At first glance it looks like you need to change line 591 to the line of code in my answer. Currently you're trying to call `setMap` on what I guess is just a number.

Comment: the error is gone i changed it to                                           
`if( mapElements[lMapElementIndex]['marker'] != 0 ){
  //map.removeOverlay(mapElements[lMapElementIndex]['marker']); v2
  mapElements[lMapElementIndex]['marker'].setMap(null); 
  console.log("[lMapElementIndex]['marker'] Löschen");
 }`

Comment: did you mean it so? it is still in the removeFromMap(lMapElementIndex) function

Comment: Thank you very much @JamesAllardice for quoting the official docs, so I also managed to re-add a marker to my map after having removed it:
`marker.setMap(map);`